# Convert From CGFloat to NSString

Tags: objective-c

I have a Fraction (CGFloat) and i want convert this result to NSString at Return.

```
- (CGFloat)add:(Fraction *)addF {

    CGFloat num = self.numerator * addF.denominator + self.denominator * addF.numerator;
    CGFloat den = self.denominator * addF.denominator;
    return num/den;
}
```

viewDidLoad:

```
Fraction *fra1 = [[Fraction alloc]initWithNumerator:4 denominator:3];

Fraction *fra2 = [[Fraction alloc]initWithNumerator:2 denominator:5];
```

Result : From 1.733... to 26/15

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the return type from `CGFloat` to `NSString`, you might also want to divide the numerator and denominator by the greatest common divisor(GCD) before doing this

```
-(NSString *)add:(Fraction *)addF {

    CGFloat num = self.numerator * addF.denominator + self.denominator * addF.numerator; 
    CGFloat den = self.denominator * addF.denominator; 
    NSString * fraction = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f/%f",num,den];
    return fraction; 
}
```

Comment: @trojanfoe thanks for pointing out, I missed it in copy paste, though I write it in words